# Merge rows with connecting dates

Tags: matlab, excel, excel-formula, vba

I've got a large Excel sheet with customer and subscription data. From this table I would like to merge records/rows with connection stop_ and start_dates and show the result in a new worksheet. A simplified version of the data is shown below.

```
Customer_id subscription_id   start_date    stop_date
1034        RV4               30-4-2012     30-1-2015
1035        AB7               30-1-2014     30-3-2014
1035        AB6               30-1-2014     30-3-2014
1035        AB7               30-12-2013    30-1-2014
1035        AB7               12-12-2012    30-12-2013
1035        AB7               12-9-2010     14-1-2011
```

So, the formula has to check the customer_id and the subscription_id. When there is a match between two or more rows in the sheet and the stop_date of one of the rows overlaps with the start_date of the other row, then after the extraction and merging, one new row must be shown with the start_date of the first and the stop_date of the other row. This also has to work if there are multiple rows with connecting dates. All the rows that don't match these criteria stay the same after the extraction. So the result will be like this:

```
Customer_id subscription_id start_date  stop_date
1034        RV4             30-4-2012   30-1-2015
1035        AB6             30-1-2014   30-3-2014
1035        AB7             12-12-2012  30-3-2014
1035        AB7             12-9-2010   14-1-2011
```

A dynamic solution would be ideal while new data will be added to the original sheet. While I know this is possible when you're certain that the rows you're looking for are always below each other, this is not the case here and it wouldn't give you a very dynamic solution.

So some kind of array function would be needed in Excel I guess but after searching a lot I couldn't find a suitable solution. I've also got MATLAB available but no clue where to start in that program with a problem like this.

Comment: seems your results contains a mistake: it should be **12-12-2012** and not **12-12-2013**

Comment: Well spotted, I corrected the mistake.

Comment: I think it is better to do it with a macro. that is why I added vba to your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic solution *may* be possible, but if the dataset it large it might bog things down quite a bit because you'd need it to run every time a cell was changed.

Basically the best way I can see to approach this is to create unique keys out your customer_id and subscription_id, then collect all of the date ranges under that key and merge them.

Something like this should get you started (requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime):

```
Public Sub LinkSubscriptionDates()

    Dim data As Dictionary, source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet

    Set source = ActiveSheet
    Set data = GetSubscriptions(source)
    Set target = source.Parent.Worksheets.Add

    'Copy headers
    target.Range(target.Cells(1, 1), target.Cells(1, 4)).Value = _
           source.Range(source.Cells(1, 1), source.Cells(1, 4)).Value

    Dim row As Long
    row = 2

    Dim key As Variant, item As Variant
    For Each key In data.Keys
        For Each item In data(key)
            target.Cells(row, 1) = Split(key, "|")(0)
            target.Cells(row, 2) = Split(key, "|")(1)
            target.Cells(row, 3) = Split(item, "|")(0)
            target.Cells(row, 4) = Split(item, "|")(1)
            row = row + 1
        Next item
    Next key

End Sub

Private Function GetSubscriptions(source As Worksheet) As Dictionary

    Dim subscrips As Dictionary
    Set subscrips = New Dictionary

    Dim row As Long
    Dim cust As String, subs As String, starting As String, ending As String

    'Gather all the data as pairs of customer|subscription, starting|ending
    For row = 2 To source.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Dim dates() As String
        cust = source.Cells(row, 1).Value
        subs = source.Cells(row, 2).Value
        'Valid customer/subscription?
        If cust <> vbNullString And subs <> vbNullString Then
            starting = source.Cells(row, 3).Value
            ending = source.Cells(row, 4).Value
            'Has an ending and starting date?
            If starting <> vbNullString And ending <> vbNullString Then
                Dim key As String
                key = cust & "|" & subs
                'New combo?
                If Not subscrips.Exists(key) Then
                    subscrips.Add key, New Collection
                    subscrips(key).Add starting & "|" & ending
                Else
                    subscrips(key).Add starting & "|" & ending
                    Set subscrips(key) = MergeDates(subscrips(key))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next row

    Set GetSubscriptions = subscrips

End Function

Private Function MergeDates(dates As Collection) As Collection

    Dim candidate As Long, index As Long
    Dim values() As String, test() As String
    Dim merge As Boolean

    For index = 1 To dates.Count
        values = Split(dates(index), "|")
        'Check to see if it can be merged with any other row.
        For candidate = index + 1 To dates.Count
            test = Split(dates(candidate), "|")
            If CDate(test(0)) >= CDate(values(0)) And _
               CDate(test(0)) <= CDate(values(1)) Or _
               CDate(test(1)) >= CDate(values(0)) And _
               CDate(test(1)) <= CDate(values(1)) Then
                dates.Remove candidate
                merge = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next candidate
        If merge Then Exit For
    Next index

    If merge Then
        'Pull both rows out of the collection.
        dates.Remove index
        values(0) = IIf(CDate(test(0)) < CDate(values(0)), _
                        CDate(test(0)), CDate(values(0)))
        values(1) = IIf(CDate(test(1)) > CDate(values(1)), _
                        CDate(test(1)), CDate(values(1)))
        'Put the merged date range back in.
        dates.Add values(0) & "|" & values(1)
        'Recurse.
        Set MergeDates = MergeDates(dates)
    End If

    Set MergeDates = dates

End Function
```

It really needs to be fleshed out with data validation, error trapping, etc., and it currently just puts the resulting data on a new worksheet. All the work gets done in the `GetSubscriptions` function, so you can just grab returned Dictionary from that and do whatever you need to do with that data in it.

Comment: Thank you, this is getting really close to what I would like to have. However the the data in the new worksheet is incorrect. A merge is performed but the result is incorrect and I can't see what causes this. From my example data above, the last row is gone after running this script and other dates are not correct. I suspect this is caused by a small error in the script but I can't identify it.

Comment: @itsme86 - Ooops.  Banged that out too fast.  Missed some casts to dates and was assuming the data was sorted.  Try the edit.

Comment: This works like a charm. Besides the 4 columns of data I've shown here there are many more columns with data but thats something I can (hopefully) get inserted in the newly created rows myself.

Comment: @itsme86 - You can always just append them to the end of the pipe delimited string that holds the dates when you're creating the Dictionary. There's nothing that says the first two elements are the only ones used.  Glad it helped.

Comment: I just found a strange error, my original dates in the worksheet are in the day-month-year format, often a month-day-year format is returned. For instance, 11-1-2013 from my original worksheet is returned in the result as 1 November 2013 instead of 11 January 2013. I can't see if this is caused by the script or by settings on my computer. Any ideas how the correct this error? I could transform the date to an 'integer' or 'double' in Excel, could the script work with that so this kind error could be prevented?

Comment: @itsme86 - Try changing all of the CDate() calls to CDbl() and see if that helps. They should be interchangeable in both VBA and excel. It may have something to do with the regional settings and how VBA is converting the dates.

Comment: I've got one final question (I promise). Currently the scripts tests for overlapping stop and start dates. However in the original data in about 10-20% of the cases that should get merged the dates are not overlapping. In these cases the start date is the day after the stop date. So a stop date of i.e. 13-12-2013 and a start date of 14-12-2013. How could this possibility be added to the other conditions in the script?

Comment: @itsme86 - That shouldn't be hard - just toss a couple `+1`'s into the line that checks for intersecting date ranges: `If CDate(test(0)) >= CDate(values(0)) + 1 And CDate(test(0)) <= CDate(values(1)) Or CDate(test(1)) >= CDate(values(0)) + 1 And CDate(test(1)) <= CDate(values(1))` or something similar should work (haven't tested).